# check folder has unique permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom

I have a Folder structure like Below RootFolder-->Folder1,Folder2-->FF2

I want to check if RootFolder has Inheritance broken like below. It is not working what i am doing wrong

```
   Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"

Function Copy-SPOFolder([String]$SiteURL, [String]$SourceFolderURL, [String]$TargetFolderURL)
{
    $Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
    Try{
        #Copy the Folder
        $MoveCopyOpt = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyOptions
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyUtil]::CopyFolder($ctx, $SourceFolderURL, $TargetFolderURL, $MoveCopyOpt)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-host -f Green "Folder Copied Successfully!" }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Copying the Folder!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
function Connect-SPO()
{
    param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)][string]$Username,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)][string]$Url,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]$AdminPassword)
    $global:ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $AdminPassword)
    $ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}

$admin="santosh@mic.com"
$pass= ConvertTo-SecureString "def" -AsPlainText -Force
$SiteURL="https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/sites/hgs_demo/"
$LibraryName="FolderTest";
$SrcFolderName="RootLibrary"
$NewFolderName="RootLibrary5"
$global:ctx
Try {
    Connect-SPO -Username $admin -Url $SiteURL -AdminPassword $pass
    $Library=$ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName);
    $Folders = $Library.RootFolder.Folders
    $ctx.Load($Library);
    $ctx.Load($Folders)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()   
  foreach($folder in $Folders)
  {

    if($folder.ItemCount -gt 0)
    {
    Write-Host $folder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
    }

  }




}

    catch{

    Write-Host  $_.Exception.Message

    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting??

Comment: There is no error basically i want to check if the folder has unique permissions or not. if it has i want to skip else break. but $folder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments is not returning any boolean value

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the error you're getting, it might be related to that you're using on-prem SharePoint CSOM libraries to connect to SharePoint Online.

I'd use [PnP PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) library like

```
$siteUrl = "https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/sites/hgs_demo"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -UseWebLogin
$context = Get-PnPContext 

$list = Get-PnPList "FolderTest"

$folders = $list.RootFolder.Folders
$context.Load($folders);
$context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach($folder in $folders)
{
  if($folder.ItemCount -gt 0)
  {    
    $f = Get-PnPFolder -Url $folder.ServerRelativeUrl -Includes ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments, ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments

    $context.Load($f);
    $context.ExecuteQuery();

    Write-Host $f.ServerRelativeUrl -> $f.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no error basically i want to check if the folder has unique permissions or not. if it has i want to skip else break. but $folder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments is not returning any boolean value

Comment: Did you try my code? It works.

Comment: Jussi no. I want it in calm. Any how I will try it in PNP and let you know . Thanks for your answer

Comment: Thank you Jussi, it works like a charm.